# Joule-Thomson effect: why does a gas cool if it's below the inversion temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

The Joule-Thomson coefficient is given by
$$\mu_{JT} = \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_{H} = \frac{V}{C_{P}}(\beta T - 1),$$
where $\beta$ is the coefficient of thermal expansion. If the inversion temperature  is defined by $T_{inv} = \frac{1}{\beta}$, then why is $\mu_{JT} > 0$ if $T < T_{inv}$, as stated by Wikipedia [Joule-Thomson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect)? I really don't get this, this should be basic math ? This results in not comprehending why a gas cools if it's below inversion temperature and vice versa.

Comment: Every mathematical model has its range of applicability.  Check to ensure that you are not exceeding that range in your calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up the coefficient of thermal expansion of air, you will find that it decreases with increasing absolute temperature.  In fact, it decreases rapidly enough that even the product $\beta T$ decreases with increasing temperature.  For air at room temperature and 1 bar, for example, the product is about 1.01 while, at 200 C, the product is about 0.99.

In terms of the compressibility factor z, the product of $\beta$ and T is given by:  $$\beta T=1+\left(\frac{\partial \ln{z}}{\partial \ln{T}}\right)_P$$So $$(\beta T-1)=\left(\frac{\partial \ln{z}}{\partial \ln{T}}\right)_P$$

Get yourself a plot of z vs reduced temperature and reduced pressure and note how the right hand side of this equation decreases with increasing reduced temperature.  It is positive at low reduced temperatures, and reaches a value of zero at a reduced temperature of about 4.