# Joule-Thomson coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm a little bit in trouble with this table on wikipedia[image: screenshot of the wikipedia article]

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect )

Since it says that when the temperature is below the inversion temperature $\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)$ then $\mu_{\text{JT}}$ is positive, considering $\alpha \cdot T -1$ is negative then. And as far as I know the temperature and $C_p$ are never negative. Am I missing something?

So what I'm asking for is: why is $\mu_{\text{JT}}$ positive if the gas temperature is below the inversion temperature?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you try to clarify this?

Comment: Why is $\mu_{JT}$ positive if the temperature is below the inversion temperature

Comment: Because lines of constant enthalpy look like https://cdn.comsol.com/cyclopedia/joule-thomson-effect/Data-plot-for-measurements.png. You can easily see that $T\left(P\right)$ increases for constant $H$ below the inversion temperature, so the derivative which is the Joule-Thomson coefficient is positive there.

Comment: yes with that formula I understand it, but not via $\frac{V}{C_p} * (\alpha T + 1)$

Comment: Of course there is a caveat here, because for example for ideal gas this is not true since $\alpha=\frac{1}{T}$ and so $\mu_{\rm JT}=0$. You have two options in my opinion - either you believe in the experimental data, or you consider a more realistic gas model that you trust and actually calculate $H$ and plot the lines of $H=\rm const.$ (which is the better option in my opinion).

Comment: is the vanderwaals model beter than?

Comment: The Van der Waals gas is excellent in this case. It can indeed accommodate cooling effects that just don't exist for ideal gas. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_temperature.

Comment: $\alpha$ decreases with increasing temperature faster than T increases, so that at temperatures below the inversion temperature (which is roughly 4-6 x the critical temperature), $\alpha T>1$ and, at temperatures above the inversion temperature, $\alpha T<1$.

Comment: @ChetMiller Is there a more fundamental reason for that? Otherwise for me it is just going in circles if we don't have a concrete model.

Comment: @eranreches Well, $\alpha$ is determined by the PVT behavior of the gas.  It can be related to how the compressibility factor varies with reduced temperature and reduced pressure.  So, derive an equation for $\alpha T-1$ in terms of the derivative of the compressibility factor with respect to reduced temperature, and then consult a generalized compressibility chart to see how this plays out.

Comment: @eranreches See the following recent thread:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483132/joule-thomson-effect-why-does-a-gas-cool-if-its-below-the-inversion-temperatur?rq=1

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks! I wasn't aware of this relation between $\mu_{\rm JT}$ and the compressibility factor.

Comment: @eranreches Neither was I.  I had never seen it before, but, in trying to address the same question in the other thread, I felt the need to derive it.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm not familiar with the mathematics of the Joule- Thompson effect, but I would really like to know your opinion of my answer, be it positive or negative. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob D The mechanism, as I understand it, is a combination of expansion cooling and viscous heating (within the valve or porous plug).  In the case of a material that behaves like an ideal gas, the two effects exactly cancel.  In the case of an incompressible liquid, the viscous heating wins out.  In the case of a real gas, depending on the starting reduced pressure and reduced temperature, either effect can prevail.

Comment: @ChetMiller So maybe my answer is incorrect? It was based on the free adiabatic expansion of a real gas where there is no change in internal energy and therefore the sum of the changes in kinetic and potential kinetic energy would be zero. Perhaps that is not the case for the throttling process?

Comment: @Bob D In the case of a throttling process, it is the change in enthalpy which is zero.  But, in both the free expansion and the throttling process, there is viscous heating of the gas or liquid associated with the irreversibility.  In free expansion, the viscous heating is the result of rapid axial elongation deformation of the gas.  In throttling, the viscous heating is the result of shear deformation of the gas in the pores of the medium.  In both cases, once this happens, the response of the gas is determined by the non-ideal PVT behavior, as you indicated in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coefficient is positive, then when the pressure goes down, so does the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal gas, a change in internal energy depends only on a change in temperature which, in turn, is only a measure of the average translational kinetic energy of the gas molecules. Since for an ideal gas there are no intermolecular (Van der waals) forces there is no change in the internal potential energy of the gas molecule during expansion or compression.

For a real gas we do have intermolecular forces. When the gas expands, there is an increase in the internal potential energy of the gas since the gas molecules separate in opposition to the intermolecular forces. The total change in internal energy of the gas is the sum of the changes in internal kinetic and potential energy. Therefore, you can have a increase in internal energy with a decrease in temperature (decrease in kinetic energy) if the increase in potential energy is greater that the decrease in kinetic energy. I believe this is why you can have a decrease in temperature without $C_P$ being negative.

However, @Chet Miller is, in my opinion, a thermodynamics expert, and I would defer to him.

Hope this helps.